# As kinect sdk V2 released, is there any library for finger tracking?

Tags: user-interface, kinect, fingerprint

I'm doing some research on finger tracking using **kinect**, and I wonder if there's a new library or open-source code doing that.

I want to get the **coordinate and the deep message of each finger and it's joint's coordinate(not only the tip)**,is there any libraries for that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does have some open-source library, but none works well...
Microsoft has developed a tech [handpose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-xXrMpOHyc)